# How to collapse expanded rows on page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help in collapsing the expanded rows which are coming by default when the page loads. Here is the javascript code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.RowToClick').click(function() {
      $(this).nextAll('tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('.RowToClick')) {
          return false;
        }
        $(this).toggle(350);
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

And below is the tr code in the table tag which collapses and expands the tr tags:

```
<tr class="RowToClick">
  <td><%=i%></td>
  <td width="20%" style="padding: 1px; cursor: pointer" title="Click Here to Expand/Collapse Sub Folders">
  <span style="text-decoration: underline"><%=sz_FolderName%></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you want to collapse in load itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below CSS:

```
.RowToClick {
      display:none;
 }
```

or add inline style

```
<tr class="RowToClick" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that in load. Place your needed HTML elements in a DIV ( or take some existing TR or as u need) say eg divID

Start you script like this

```
     $('#divID').toggle();
```

Try this script :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("table").each(function() {
         $("tr").each(function() {
             if ($(this).hasClass('RowToClick')) {
                       }
              else {
                                $(this).toggle(50);
                    }
                });
       });

       $('.RowToClick').click(function ()
                 {
                     $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function()
                     {
                         if ($(this).is('.RowToClick'))
                        {
                           return false;
                        }
                        $(this).toggle(350);
                     });
                 });

         });
```

Update :

Can you try this fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/riginvp/xgeth4br/4/

Comment: Yes, I want on the page load. Currently all the rows are expanded. Do you mean that the full table should be in the div? Or I should refer to an empty div?Should I place it above the document?

Comment: Do you need first ROW of table to be there and rest all below rows to be collapsed ?

Comment: Just add one more portion in your script. ok

Comment: opps, dont know why, But it worked for me. Hope you got another answer anyhow. I could have given u a Fiddle